# How assign var Array to string Array jQuery? MVC3 Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the next code of jQuery:

```
function getParameter() {
    var valor = [];
    $("input[name='TiposServicioSeleccionados']:checked").each(function (i) {
        valor.push($(this).val());
    });
    if (valor.length == 0) {
        valor.push("0");
    }

    return {
        nofacturados: $("#nofacturados:checked").val(),
        precioactual: $("#precioactual:checked").val(),
        TiposServicioSeleccionados: valor
    };
}
```

I want to assing 'valor' to 'TiposServicioSeleccionados', in my controller I have this

```
public ActionResult LeerExt_DevolucionRepuesto(string[] TiposServicioSeleccionados, bool? facturados, bool? nofacturados)
        {
            int id_empresaservicio = Convert.ToInt16(Session["id_empresaservicio"]);
            var res = GetDevolucionRepuestos(TiposServicioSeleccionados,facturados,nofacturados);

            return Json(res.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
```

but always TiposServicioSeleccionados is null, I don't know why...

I call `getParameter` in:

```
Read(read => read.Action("LeerExt_DevolucionRepuesto", "Consultas").Data("getParameter"))
```

I need, For example, if I checked three checkbox, in `TiposServicioSeleccionados` I want to save the next values: `TiposServicioSeleccionados[0]="value of the first chekbox"`,`TiposServicioSeleccionados[1]="value of the second chekbox"`, `TiposServicioSeleccionados[2]="value of the third chekbox"`

Regards

Comment: Not an answer, but it is better to use `.push` to add an element and `.length` to check if the array is empty. `valor.push($(this).val());` and `if (valor.length == 0) { valor.push("0"); }`

Comment: thanks..I'm going to change that part!

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and use push for adding array objects

```
function getParameter() {
 var valor = [];
 $("input[name='TiposServicioSeleccionados']:checked").each(function (i) {
    valor.push($(this).val());
 });
 if (valor.length == 0) {
    valor.push("0");
 }

return {

    TiposServicioSeleccionados: JSON.stringify(valor)
};
```

}

Comment: I tried that but in 'TiposServicioSeleccionados' exist a value only in possition [0], that value is "[\"7\",\"6\",\"10\"]". I need, For example, if I checked three checkbox in 'TiposServicioSeleccionados' the next values:
'TiposServicioSeleccionados[0]="7"','TiposServicioSeleccionados[1]="6"', 'TiposServicioSeleccionados[2]="10"'

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine, take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tXAn6/

I added 3 checkboxes and manually selected the first and the third one.

```
... value="Servicio A" checked /> A
... value="Servicio B" /> B
... value="Servicio C" checked /> C
```

The result is:

`Servicio A, Servicio C`

**Edit:**

`TiposServicioSeleccionados` should not be Capitalize, as it is a variable it should start with downcase `tiposServicioSeleccionados`.

By convection: `functionNamesLikeThis`, `variableNamesLikeThis`, `ClassNamesLikeThis`, `EnumNamesLikeThis`, `methodNamesLikeThis`, and `SYMBOLIC_CONSTANTS_LIKE_THIS`.